# apache itk - a lot of processes hanging

Tags: apache-2.2

Have problem with my current setup. I'm on Debian 7 with apache2.2 itk + php. The problem is, that under normal circumstances I see about 30-50 apache processes, but after sometime apache processes count is more then 300. All processes are idle. In /server-status they have "W" Status - sending reply. And they hang in that way a lot of time (days) until I reboot apache. Could someone please help and make a guess what it can be?

Answer (score 0):

There is may be many reasons - network lags, slow clients and so on. Nginx may help to resolve this problems if install it as reverse proxy before apache. Apache's worker process will be released immediately after response was generated, because it sends it to nginx, listening on same host and nginx will send response back to client.

There are many howto around the internet about such configuration, e.g:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-front-end-proxy-for-apache